# Can't create Google oAuth clientId becuase of the consent screen

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to get Google oAuth `clientId` but it says:

`To create an OAuth client ID, you must first set a product name on the consent screen`

[image]

So, when I click on **Configure Consent Screen**:

[image]

In my app, I'm using passport.js and google's oAuth20.My app can let anyone log in with a google account. And for that I need the `clientId`.

But it says to choose `Internal` and `External` option. I don't know what's this. The consent screen was not there before.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

The consent screen is primarily used by Google to understand your application. Internal means **within organization** and external refers to **any user**. So whenever you setup your application for the first time, Google wants to understand who you are building this application for.Just follow this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) for the entire Oauth setup procedure

Comment: @htheory226 then put **external** and complete the process